# Is there a simpler way to write this Java GUI window code?

Tags: java, swing, io

I'm studying code that simply shows a full-screen color and cycles through other colors. There's a line I've been staring at

```
getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false), "ESCAPE");
```

This allows you to press "Esc" and quit it( and getRootPane() is associated with JButton I think?). But Is there a more efficient way to code  this?  Can it be split up into multiple lines?

Comment: It can be split up into lots of lines, but that doesn't make it more efficient. Are you just trying to make it easier to read?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
InputMap inputMap = getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
KeyStroke escapeStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false);
inputMap.put(escapeStroke, "Escape");
```

While this would appear more readable, I don't think this would add anything in terms of efficiency to the current implementation.

Comment: This would actually make it less efficient, since it has to create instances of those classes and retain them until garbage collection swings through.

Comment: @RileyE - Instances of `InputMap` and `KeyStroke` are created whether or not you assign them to anything. If the instances weren't created, how would the JVM pass them as arguments (or receivers) to the method calls? References to these objects are stored inside the root pane too, so they can't be GC'd at the end of this call. The only thing that might be less efficient is the compiler might allocate 2 extra slots on the stack to hold local references, which just get popped off in constant time when the method returns anyway.

Comment: Sorry. I was up late. I meant pointers. It would still have to iterate over them in garbage collection. Its not really a performance hit, but its still something.